# Formatting number in javascript(typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way in javascript or Typescript to format decimal?

For example:

- 1.33 => 1.35
- 1.32 => 1.35

All i found was formatting to 2 decimals, but i need it to format to nearest .05

Comment: 1.32 is closer to 1.3 than 1.35.

Comment: @Drasko your question is not exactly the same try this fiddle for exact answer https://jsfiddle.net/fn3tso4k/1/

Comment: Yeah my mistake, that should be round to 1.30, sry :)

Answer (score 0):

This function uses `Math.round` and multiplies and divides by 0.05 because it is to the nearest 0.05.

```js
function tN(n) {
    return Math.round(n / 0.05) * 0.05;
}

console.log(tN(1.33));

console.log(tN(1.32));

console.log(tN(0.05));

console.log(tN(-1.08));
```

If all outputs have to end in a 5:

```js
function tN(n) {
    return n % 0.1 > 0.05 ? Math.floor(n / 0.05) * 0.05 : Math.ceil(n / 0.05) * 0.05;
}

console.log(tN(1.33));

console.log(tN(1.32));

console.log(tN(0.05));

console.log(tN(-1.08));
```

Comment: Please edit your answer. According to the question's description it is wrong. In the question it is written that `1.32 -> 1.35` but in your answer it is `1.3`. You have created a function that rounds numbers to 0.05, in order to have the logic that the question wants you should use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.round`.

Comment: `Math.ceil` would not work because then inputting 1.08 would give 1.1.

Comment: Still for 1.32 you should provide 1.35 so the answer is not accurate. In the question is asked that numbers from .01 to .05 should point to .05 and numbers from .06 to .09 should point to .05 also.

Comment: I've created a separate function that outputs only numbers ending in 5.

Comment: It was my mistake... 1.32 should be round to 1.30 sry :D